# Informative priors from frequentist regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior

Say I run a standard frequentist regression on a subset of my data (for example using lm in R) and obtain some values for the coefficients of the model, I have fairly large data set ~100k samples. Now I run a bayesian regression over the remaining held out data using the lm beta values as priors (i.e. normally distributed centered at the value). Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: I personally wouldn't have a problem with that, although with a smallish sample I'd probably build a hierarchical prior with a prior on a scale parameter multiplying the covariance matrix of the betas.  On the other hand, with 100K samples, how large are the standard errors of the coefficients, anyway?

Comment: Isn't that what some people call a training sample prior?

Comment: I should have prefaced this by saying the main goal of this is in attempt estimate some interactions of interest.